# Dropbox API (v2) returns "Invalid shared folder ID."

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to query basic folder metadata with [the new Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation), through an HTTP request. I can use the endpoints `files/list_folder` and `files/get_metadata` with no problem, but my calls to `sharing/get_folder_metadata` are returning this:

```
{"error_summary": "invalid_id/", "error": {".tag": "invalid_id"}, "user_message": {"locale": "unknown", "text": "Invalid shared folder ID."}}
```

I have tried this with a few different folder IDs—the numerical ID that was used in the v1 API, and also the hash-like ID returned by, e.g., `files/list_folder` (which are all prefixed with `id:`). All of these produce the same result:

```
{"shared_folder_id":"976667947","include_membership":true}
{"shared_folder_id":"id:976667947","include_membership":true}
{"shared_folder_id":"2PUz957E_toAAAAAAAAAkQ","include_membership":true}
{"shared_folder_id":"id:2PUz957E_toAAAAAAAAAkQ","include_membership":true}
```

(I've scrambled some numbers/letters above, but in my test code I am copying and pasting the IDs returned by the API itself.)

How am I to indicate the `shared_folder_id`?

(I should note that this endpoint is marked in the docs as being in beta. It may also be significant that none of the endpoints in the [API Explorer](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/) take `shared_folder_id` as an input.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared folder IDs that should be used here are available in a few places in Dropbox API v2, e.g., from [/sharing/list_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http#documentation-sharing-list_folders), where the response contains an `entries` field, which is a list of `SharedFolderMetadata`, each of which has an `id`.

The `id` would look something like:

> dbsfid:AAAhfghd_efhgfgeJfgwUm-SOyhgffgY